# Bent prong on my stove top Burner element - still work if I bend it back

Tags: electrical, stove-top

I have an old electric stove top. The burner is going bad so a bought a new one online and the prongs were bent. My question is if I straighten them will it still work well. What is the inner part of the burner element? Is it wire or can it handle being bent? I don't know how the heating element works. I don't want to go through removing the old one to put one on that won't work any better. I already bent them back so can't really tell the EBAY guy it was bent when I can't show a picture. So might be stuck with it so wondering if it will still work like it is supposed to. Here is a link to the item I bought. http://www.ebay.com/itm/162201812960?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT - If that doesn't work it is like this product - http://www.partselect.com/PS244048-GE-WB30X354-Tilt-Lock-Hinge-Mounted-Surface-Burner-8.htm

Basically - two of the prongs (ones on the left were bent -one slightly the other almost 90 degrees) I bent them straight and I'm asking if it will work as it should. Thanks

Comment: Do you have an ohmmeter or multimeter?  If so it is very easy to check.  If not, today's as good a day as any to buy one :)

Comment: If the metal jacket did not crack it may work, as suggested by @Grant the reading should be 10-20 ohms if it is 2450 w depending on the element voltage . If the jacket cracked toss it and get a new one.

Comment: Wish I could say I understood any of that... just a homeowner trying to replace a burner that doesn't heat evenly anymore.  What is the jacket part of the prong?  I can tell you where it was bent.  If you start at the top of the prong/the screw connection and go down towards the burner.  There is the thinner metal that is attached to the tip and then it gets thicker as it meets what I think is the inner insulator and an outer layer that will form the burner surface (sorry don't see a way to add a pic).

Comment: So it was bent right where the metal meets the insulator and outer metal  or beginning of the burner coil.  The part that was bent was the metal that is attached to the tip and before it gets to the main coil/insulated part. About 1 - 1.5 inches in. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: If it isn't supposed to be bent, why not take it back for replacement rather than guessing?

Comment: Because I got it on Ebay and bent it back before I took a picture to prove it arrived damaged.  My bad.